# Doll reborning paints

Tags: paint, doll-reborning

I am new to reborning, and I am concerned about the use of heat set paints and vapours released from heating the vinyl doll parts to set the paint.

I have been looking at air drying paints as a safer option, but would like to know if the finish is as professional and realistic looking as using the heat set paint.

Comment: I've seen people use water colour paint/pencil or acrylic paint and then a sealant. Not something I do though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the process involved and the toxicity and the heat setting relate directly to the vinyl paints *bonding* with the base material to essentially become one complex surface.

Air drying paints on top of the plastic will not have the same translucency as the bonded vinyl paints so I think the answer is no as far as "realism" goes since it is the translucency, also known as subsurface scattering, that is mimicking the behavior of light on real skin.